# samsung galaxy s cannot add google account

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

My HTC was run over by a bus and I am temporarily using my Samsung Galaxy S whilst the phone is being repaired.

I discovered yesterday that my google account was syncing.  I was able to login into my gmail via the internet but the account would not allow me to sign in via the gmail/ youtube or market app.

From reading around it appears these apps need to be updated but there is no update option in settings.

When I try to access the play store via the browser to download , it says it is no longer supported.

Any ideas?

Comment: I assume you added your account through, Settings > Accounts > Google. or ran the setup for the device? You could also try removing your account from the device and readding it.

One thing you could try is going into the settings, Look for App Manager and find the play store, Clear the data for the app. Then try relaunching it.

Comment: No play store, only android market .

Comment: there's your answer. if you have android market, its wayyyy out of date

Comment: @DanB I know but how to I get play store?  Is it even possible?  Is there a way to update market to play?

Comment: There should be

Comment: @DanB I agree.  In end I created a new gmail account.  It just would not let me use my old email account, no idea why....